# Soap API call through a load balancer

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, soap

I have a `java app/client` which calls a `soap` web service using `Java Sockets`. Now I need to add a `load balancer` in between the client and server which redirects the request to multiple `Tomcat` instances where the `API` is running. How can you establish `socket` connection from the `client` without specifying the `server port` address since the routing happens through the `load balancer(F5)`? Can this be accomplished through `F5` configuration somehow?

For instance the soap url looks like this:

http://abc:1234/myapp/mysoap?wsdl

It needs to be converted to

http://abc/myapp/mysoap?wsdl

Comment: We use F5's and Virtual IP's in front of may of our web services and everything works fine - grant it we dont use sockets (instead usually HTTP package) requests but you should'nt have any issues.  I think you might be thinking about it wrong - you'll still use the port else it would default to HTTP/80 and the F5 is configured to listen to traffic on that port and VIP and when a requests comes in, the F5 can be configured to load balance it to 2 or more servers on their respective ports.

Comment: It works now.,I can access the tomcat server through localhost:port# from within the client  app without having to route it through the load balancer. It's not ideal solution as it always goes to one server. But its ok.

Comment: Glad to here you got it working!  Another alternative is add your own basic load balancing to your client, servers down, try the other - or if its true load balancing, send every other request to the other server, then if its down try the primary again!